# How to access Express parameters on HTML without using Jade?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

After Rendering my page to HTML

```
res.render('myPage', myParameters);
```

how can I then access `myParameters`on my HTML+js page ? (without using Jade)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using Consolidate renderer instead of jade:

```
var cons = require('consolidate');

app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

and then to access it on js it's as simple as using `{{ varname }}`, ex: :

```
var myParameters = "{{myParameters}}";
```